# ASP.net mvc EntityCollection is null when saving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been trying to figure this out for over a day now but I just can't get this to work.
I have an asp.net MVC website which uses the entityframework for its datamodel.
I need to be able to edit a complex `Release` entity which contains a `List<ReleaseDescription>`

I have the following model (Apparantly I cannot upload pictures so I'll just type it out):

```
public class Release
{
    public string Version
    ..some other primitive properties
    public EntityCollection<ReleaseDescription>
}

public class ReleaseDescription
{
    public string Description
    public Language Language
}

public class Language
{
    public string ISOCode
    public string Description
}
```

When looking for a solution for this problem on the web. I found out that using an EntityCollection (see list `Release.ReleaseDescription`) is not a good idea so in the partial class `Release` I made an extra property `ReleaseDescriptionList` which transforms this entityCollection into a `List<ReleaseDescription>` through the getter, it has no setter.

The problem is that, when saving, my `release.ReleaseDescription` or even the `release.ReleaseDescriptionList` is always empty when items should be in it.

Here follows the rest of my code:

My Edit.aspx code looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Server.DM.Release>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        ... (Code for the primitive properties (works all fine)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Descriptions</legend>

                <% for(var i =0; i<Model.ListReleaseDescriptions.Count; i++)
                {%>
                   <%: Html.EditorFor(x => Model.ListReleaseDescriptions[i], "ReleaseDescriptionRow")%>
                <%} %>

                <%= Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "AddDescription", Model) %>

        </fieldset>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>

    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

The asp code in the DescriptionRelease looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Server.DM.ReleaseDescription>" %>Language: <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Language.ISOCode) %>Qty: <%=Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description)%>
```

(I couldn't get above codeblock on multiple lines sorry)

When I click the save button in the edit screen and I get to my ActionController

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Release release)
```

`release.DescriptionRelease` does not contain any data when 3 items should be in it.
Any help is appreciated in resolving this issue!

(ps: yes I know there are similar threads on this forum and others but none of it seems to work for me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, After a lot of searching I finally found an answer for my problem.

I already made an extra property to make up for the EntityCollection but it looked like this:

```
public IList<ReleaseDescription> ListReleaseDescription
{
    get
    {
        return ReleaseDescription.ToList();
    }
}
```

That didn't work so I made a simple property out of it like so:

```
public IList<ReleaseDescription> ListReleaseDescription{get; set;}
```

and I populated this property in my controller. This finally fixed my problem and I got all the data back when saving! I can't believe I wasted 1,5 days on this when the solution was this simple.